# Possible to make tweens happen at the same time with Greensock Timelinelite?

Tags: actionscript-3, asynchronous, tween

Is it possible to make tweens happen at the same time with Greensock Timelinelite?

I know it could be possible to fake it by putting a negative delay in but that's not very accurate.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `TweenAlign.START` to align all of them at the same point, like this:

```
var tweens : Array = [
    new TweenLite(mc, 1, {y:"100"}),
    new TweenLite(mc2, 1, {x:20})
    new TweenLite(mc3, 1, {alpha:0.5})
]
myTimeline.insertMultiple( tweens, 0, TweenAlign.START);
```

or you can insert them all at the same point in time separately too:

```
var startPoint : int = 2; //seconds

myTimeline.insert( new TweenLite(mc, 1, {y:"100"}), startPoint );
myTimeline.insert( new TweenLite(mc2, 1, {x:20}), startPoint );
myTimeline.insert( new TweenLite(mc3, 1, {alpha:0.5}), startPoint );
```

Comment: Thanks Creynders, that's awesome!